# How to remove one of the objects when they collide each other

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am creating a game where random objects will fall and if one of the objects touches the player, then the object will disappear. I tried using particles.splice, but it didn't work. Any idea how to remove the object when they collide with each other ?

```
function hitDetect(m, mi) {
  var e = mi;
  if (m.x + m.w >= e.x && m.x <= e.x + e.w && m.y >= e.y && m.y <= e.y + e.h) {
    if (mi >= -1)
      particles.splice(this.particles[mi], 1);
    // Remove the object that touches the player
    // particles.splice(this.particles[mi],1);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are missing a "this". Also, this.particles.splice(this.particles.indexOf(mi), 1)

Comment: Try to properly format your code next time.

Comment: What is the variable `mi` ?   An index into the `particles` array ?  What is `this` - have you ensured that it refers to some particular object created with a constructor ?  Are there any errors in your browser's JS console ?